# Koa-router. Need to stay on page. AJAX? How?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, koa, koa-router

Code block for router is like below:

```
router
    .get('/', function* (next) {
      this.body = dot.main(some_data);
    })
    .post('/some_operation', function* (next) {
      //code for sending data to DB
      //this.body = dot.main(some_data);
     });
```

I need to send some data to DB with post request while staying on the same page (not reloading the page). If I use "this.body ..." line, page gets reloaded. Not using it gives "Not found" displayed (which is logical). How can I do something like AJAX in order to send data to DB asynchronously not reloading the page?

Comment: Don't do something "like AJAX". Just use AJAX … which is a client side technology … so your server side code is largely irrelevant.

Comment: Do you want to send data from server to client?

Comment: Fell myself stupid... Thanks guys. AJAX is the solution. @Quentin